# Obtener propiedades de objetos al recibir string como argumento Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, bucles, objeto

Estoy trabado con un ejercicio de js en el cual recibo un string como argumento de la función, este string si es igual a la propiedad A y debe devolver la propiedad B

Estoy intentando iterar el array de objetos pero mi código devuelve un string vacío. Debería devolver un string con la frecuencia que corresponde a la actividad dada

Las primeras 5 funciones ya están solucionadas, solo falta la última que no he logrado conseguir solucionar aún...

El ejercicio es este:

```
function crearClaseMascota() {
  class Mascota {
    constructor(nombre, dueño, actividades) {
      // El constructor de la clase Mascota recibe nombre (string), dueño (objeto), actividades (array de objetos)
      // ej:
      //[{actividad: 'salir a caminar', frecuencia: '1 vez al dia'}, {actividad: 'baño', frecuencia: '1 vez al mes'}]
      // Inicializar las propiedades de la mascota.nombrelos valores recibidos como argumento
      // Tu código aca:
      this.nombre = nombre,
      this.dueño = dueño,
      this.actividades = actividades;
    }

    getNombre() {
      // este método debe retornar el nombre de la mascota.
      // Tu código aca:
      // var savePetName = ((pet) => pet.nombre);
      // var petName = this.Mascota.map(savePetName);
      // return petName;
      return this.nombre;
    }

    getDueño() {
      // El método debe retornar nombre y apellido del dueño (concatenados).
      // Tu código aca:
      return this.dueño.nombre + ' ' + this.dueño.apellido;
    }

    addActividad(actividad, frecuencia) {
      // El método recibe un string 'actividad' y otro string 'frecuencia'  y debe agregarlo al arreglo de actividades de la mascota.nombre      // No debe retornar nada.
      // Tu código aca:
      var newActivity = {
        actividad: actividad,
        frecuencia: frecuencia
      };
      this.actividades.push(newActivity);
    }

    getActividades() {
      // El método debe retornar un arreglo con sólo las actividades de las mascotas.
      // Ej:
      // [{actividad: 'salir a caminar', frecuencia: '1 vez al dia'}, {actividad: 'baño', frecuencia: '1 vez al mes'}]
      // mascotas.getActividades() debería devolver ['salir a caminar, 'baño']
      // Tu código aca:
      var saveActivity = ((pet) => pet.actividad);
      var nameActivity = this.actividades.map(saveActivity);
      return nameActivity;
    }

    getFrecuencia(actividad) {
        // El metodo debe retornar la frecuencia de dicha actividad
        // ej:
        // [{actividad: 'salir a caminar', frecuencia: '1 vez al dia'}, {actividad: 'baño', frecuencia: '1 vez al mes'}]
        // mascotas.getFrecuencia('baño') debería devolver '1 vez al mes'
        // Tu código aca:
      var actividadStr = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < this.actividades; i++) {
        if (actividad === this.actividades[i].actividad) {
          actividadStr = this.actividades[i].frecuencia;
        }
      } return actividadStr;
    }
  }

  return Mascota;
}
```

Comment: Falta mucho contexto para poderte ayudar. No vemos la definición de la clase, ni lo que es `this.actividades`. En resumen, te falta un [example] para poder considerar darte una respuesta válida. Léete [ask] y [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio, gracias.

Comment: En la definición del bucle te falta el límite superior para el iterando: `i < this.actividades.length`. Te faltó poner la propiedad `length` del Array de actividades. Saludos

Comment: Añadiré la función completa que indicas. Dentro de esta función hay 6 ejercicios de los que ya resolví 5. Solo me falta el que se llama getFrecuencia(actividad)

Comment: Amigo, muchas gracias! No me había dado cuenta que me faltó el .length... Llevaba horas con esto ajajaj

Comment: ¿No crees que sería más fácil si `actividades` fuera un diccionario? Podrías acceder a la frecuencia así: `actividades[actividad]`

Answer (score 0):

Me faltaba el .length

Dejo acá como queda al final por si a alguien le sirve para futuras referencias:

```
function crearClaseMascota() {
  class Mascota {
    constructor(nombre, dueño, actividades) {
      // El constructor de la clase Mascota recibe nombre (string), dueño (objeto), actividades (array de objetos)
      // ej:
      //[{actividad: 'salir a caminar', frecuencia: '1 vez al dia'}, {actividad: 'baño', frecuencia: '1 vez al mes'}]
      // Inicializar las propiedades de la mascota.nombrelos valores recibidos como argumento
      // Tu código aca:
      this.nombre = nombre,
      this.dueño = dueño,
      this.actividades = actividades;
    }

    getNombre() {
      // este método debe retornar el nombre de la mascota.
      // Tu código aca:
      // var savePetName = ((pet) => pet.nombre);
      // var petName = this.Mascota.map(savePetName);
      // return petName;
      return this.nombre;
    }

    getDueño() {
      // El método debe retornar nombre y apellido del dueño (concatenados).
      // Tu código aca:
      return this.dueño.nombre + ' ' + this.dueño.apellido;
    }

    addActividad(actividad, frecuencia) {
      // El método recibe un string 'actividad' y otro string 'frecuencia'  y debe agregarlo al arreglo de actividades de la mascota.nombre      // No debe retornar nada.
      // Tu código aca:
      var newActivity = {
        actividad: actividad,
        frecuencia: frecuencia
      };
      this.actividades.push(newActivity);
    }

    getActividades() {
      // El método debe retornar un arreglo con sólo las actividades de las mascotas.
      // Ej:
      // [{actividad: 'salir a caminar', frecuencia: '1 vez al dia'}, {actividad: 'baño', frecuencia: '1 vez al mes'}]
      // mascotas.getActividades() debería devolver ['salir a caminar, 'baño']
      // Tu código aca:
      var saveActivity = ((pet) => pet.actividad);
      var nameActivity = this.actividades.map(saveActivity);
      return nameActivity;
    }

    getFrecuencia(actividad) {
        // El metodo debe retornar la frecuencia de dicha actividad
        // ej:
        // [{actividad: 'salir a caminar', frecuencia: '1 vez al dia'}, {actividad: 'baño', frecuencia: '1 vez al mes'}]
        // mascotas.getFrecuencia('baño') debería devolver '1 vez al mes'
        // Tu código aca:
      var actividadStr = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < this.actividades.length; i++) {
        if (actividad === this.actividades[i].actividad) {
          actividadStr = this.actividades[i].frecuencia;
        }
      } return actividadStr;
    }
  }

  return Mascota;
}
```